# Getting dir path for file in argument in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

I'm using argparse to send .pcap's to a script that scrapes through them. Wanted to organize what I was doing better, so I threw the data I was using in one folder and my scripts in another. Interfered with the way I was saving IP lists/hostnames (filename now tries to just add 'IP-list-' before the path to the .pcap file I sent as an argument).

```
        new_ips_filename = '/IP-list-' + self.pcap
        new_ips_file = open(new_ips_filename[:-5], 'w')
        for i in range(len(self.new_ips)):
            new_ips_file.write(self.new_ips[i] + ':' + self.new_hostnames[i] + '\n')
        new_ips_file.close()
```

self.pcap is the path to the .pcap (which would just be ./file.pcap if it were in the same dir), is there any easy way to pull the dir from the filename here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the absolute path of the file?
You might try os.path.abspath("file.pcap")
Or if you want only the directory name os.path.dirname(..)

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit or a comment.